# Running PowerShell Script in real PowerShell Window

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-prompt

When I type this command in a classic windows command promt (black, small, not full resizable, small pre defined scroll buffer)

```
powershell myScript.ps1
```

The script will be executed in the classic command prompt window.
But I want to have a real power shell window (blue background, bigger, full resizable, "endless" scolling).
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly, you just want to have a powshell window instead of a cmd one. open a powershell window by typing powershell in start->run

you can just ./myScript.ps1 to execute your script, assuming that your execution policy is set up properly already.

Comment: The Script i want to run is about to perform several checks on the files in the current directory. So if i would start PS from the start menu i would have to navigate to my (very deep) path first. For the CMD i can right click the folder while having shift pressed and select "Command Prompt from here". There is a registry tweak for having a "Powershell from here" but this also opens a PS in a CMD. :-/

Comment: Oh I see, maybe this will help. http://superuser.com/questions/287221/how-to-open-a-powershell-in-the-current-folder, but you can edit your cmd properties to make it look exactly like powershell by changing fonts, color, etc. Or you can use $Profile to make sure that when powershell runs, you will have these settings even though it is running in a cmd window.

Comment: Ok, that the PowerShell Window is just a customized CMD window, was what i found out in the last minutes, too. Thought PS-Win and CMD-Win were two different things. So i modified the standard prefs for CMD and everything is fine :)